# fade changing image every n seconds

Tags: jquery, html, fade

I want to change an image every 3 seconds, but when changing I want to make a fade effect, to do so I was doing:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var images = [];
    images[0] = "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/Q1yo3mco40U/default.jpg";
    images[1] = "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/ivmoCcYLrEk/default.jpg";
    images[2] = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/f7d8luQ6p2Q/default.jpg";
    images[3] = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XzFmOKNf8sc/default.jpg";
    images[4] = "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/-2m1e4g2MFM/default.jpg";
    images[5] = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/lK2TSYBh7fw/default.jpg";
    var loop;
    var i = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(fadeDivs, 3000);   
    });

    function fadeDivs()
    {
        $('.product img').attr('src',images[i]).fadeOut(100);
        if (i < images.length - 1) {
            i++;                                
        } else {
            i = 0;                
        } 
    }
  </script>
```

and:

```
<section id="product">
    <article class="product">
      <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/Q1yo3mco40U/default.jpg" />
    </article>
</section>
```

However is not working, I think the problem is in

```
$('.product img').attr('src',images[i]).fadeOut(100);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

[here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YmrB/)

Comment: in your fiddle,jQuery inclusion is missing.. add that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` along with the complete callbacks to do it

```
var images = [];
images[0] = "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/Q1yo3mco40U/default.jpg";
images[1] = "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/ivmoCcYLrEk/default.jpg";
images[2] = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/f7d8luQ6p2Q/default.jpg";
images[3] = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XzFmOKNf8sc/default.jpg";
images[4] = "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/-2m1e4g2MFM/default.jpg";
images[5] = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/lK2TSYBh7fw/default.jpg";

var i = 0;
setInterval(fadeDivs, 3000);

function fadeDivs() {
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
    $('.product img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
    })
    i++;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vm3Cv/)

*Note: In the fiddle, you missed to include jQuery*

Comment: How to set an interval? Is it necessary?

Comment: @cMinor sorry... what do you mean.... the `setInterval` is used because the function `fadeDivs` has to be called at regular intervals

Comment: Minor JS async error...by the time the anonymous function (passed to the fadeOut call) is run the value of i has moved forward and so you are actually viewing the next image (i++)
Moving the **i++;** inside the function block resolves the issue