# How to change image with fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm quite new to js and jquery and I'm trying to do something very simple with my Rails app: I want to switch between 2 images every 3 seconds with a fading effect. Of course, this question was already asked on StackOverflow but I couldn't make it work for me, unfortunately.

I based my vain attempts on those two questions:

[Change image in HTML page every few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-in-html-page-every-few-seconds) (Automatic change without fade)

[fade changing image every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996053/fade-changing-image-every-n-seconds) (Automatic change with fade)

I managed to make it work with an automatic change but without any fade effect. Here is my code for this:

**HTML code** (located in a view page, let's say index.html.erb)

```
<div class="container p-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="display-5 mb-4">Title here</h2>
            <p class="lead">Lead</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img id="img" src="http://localhost:3000/images/pdf_template.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery code** (located in the head of my application.html.erb file)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function displayNextImage() {
        x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
        document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
    }

    function startTimer() {
        setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
    }

    var images = [], x = -1;
    images[0] = "http://localhost:3000/images/pdf_template.png";
    images[1] = "http://localhost:3000/images/watermark_template.png";
</script>
```

For it to work, I changed the body tag from `<body>` to `<body onload = "startTimer()">`

With the previous code, I have an image that changes automatically every 3 seconds.

I then tried to use the second link I provided to implement the fade effect, to no success.

The HTML code is the same of course.

**jquery code**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var images = [];
    images[0] = "http://localhost:3000/images/pdf_template.png";
    images[1] = "http://localhost:3000/images/watermark_template.png";

    var x = 0;
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);

    function displayNextImage() {
        x = x < images.length - 1 ? x : 0;
        $("#img").fadeOut(300, function(){
          $(this).attr('src', images[x]).fadeIn(300);
        })
        x++;
    }
</script>
```

It's really strange because I used the jsfiddle in the second link I provided to test my jquery code and it works perfectly there. I suspect there might be something wrong with my Rails app, maybe I didn't place the script in the right place? For now, it is in the head tag but maybe it's wrong.

I'm using Rails 5.2.3, jquery-rails 4.3.5, jquery 3.2.1

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is your `$(document).ready` declaration (or `$(document).on "turbolinks:load"` if your using `turbolinks`)? It might be helpful to take a look at the guide on [Working with Javascript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks).

Comment: Mmh, I didn't do any (to be honest I didn't know what it was until you commented it). I just looked for it on google and if I understood correctly it's to show that the page is ready for the javascript to execute, and the code in this declaration will only be run once. I don't understand how it can help me. Can you please enlighten me? Thanks @jvillian for your answer.

Comment: @jvillian After some research the problem was indeed coming from the lack of a ```$(document).ready``` block. Now everything is working fine (I opened another question for this). thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JQuery .animate function and I guess it might also work for you.

Here is an example of how I managed to get the animation and fade effect done when changing the src attribute of the image control:

```
        //Refresh the thumbnail
        $(".photo-container").animate({
            opacity: 0.10,
        }, 200, function () {
            $(".photo-info").attr("src", photo);
            ReloadGallery(currentContext); // Just showing extra logic can be use here...
        }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200);
```

It follows 3 steps:

1. Fades out the photo-container div by diminishing the Opacity to 0.10.
2. Executes the callback function after the 200 milliseconds that last the opacity change action of the first step. This function is the one that takes care of changing the src attribute of the image and refreshing the gallery or any other things you need to do.
3. The animation kicks-in again by restoring the opacity of the container back to 1.

Hope this give you a possible idea of how to get your logic working.

regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working now with your answer. I didn't use the `ReloadGallery(currentContext);` in my case. If anyone needs the code just ask me and I will post an answer here.

Comment: Correct, Reload gallery is not necessary in your case, that is just pat of my example to show the extra logic can go there. Great it worked!

Comment: I ran it without any trouble the first time, but now it doesn't work anymore even though I made no change. I inspected the web console and saw this error: `TypeError: $("#img").animate is not a function.` I investigated a bit and saw that, in fact, it is the root of my problem, the code I posted above gives me the same error. I opened a new question for this, if you have 5 minutesyou can check it out :) thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510588/typeerror-is-not-a-function-in-rails-app

Comment: The idea on the code I shared is to apply the animate action to the container holding the image control. That way you can hide the container for a bit, then change the src attribute value, and restore the container's opacity back to normal.