# TypeError, is not a function in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm quite new to js and jquery and I'm trying to do something very simple for my Rails app: I want to switch between 2 images every 3 seoncs with a fading effect. The problem is that I'm obtaining an error but don't know how to solve it (it's a typical error from what I've read but I had no luck in fixing it). I tested my code with jsfiddle and it works fine but when I run my app I get this error in the web console:

```
TypeError: $("#img").fadeOut is not a function.
```

Here is my code:

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container p-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="display-5 mb-4">Title here</h2>
            <p class="lead">Lead</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img id="img" src="http://localhost:3000/images/pdf_template.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery code**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
      var images = [];
      images[0] = "http://localhost:3000/images/pdf_template.png";
      images[1] = "http://localhost:3000/images/watermark_template.png";

      var x = 0;
      setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = x < images.length - 1 ? x : 0;
          $("#img").fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).attr('src', images[x]).fadeIn(300);
          })
          x++;
      }
</script>
```

As I said, the code is working in a jsfiddle, so I suspect the problem is coming from my rails app but I didn't find anything relevant on google about it. The jquery code is located in my application.html.erb, in the head of the file. I managed to make some other jquery code works (an automatic image change but without fade effect) without any issue but this won't work.

I'm using Rails 5.2.3, jquery-rails 4.3.5, jquery 3.2.1

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: with jquery, good practice is to wrap your functions in a document ready block, so the dom is loaded before you execute the function. `$(document).ready(your goodies);`

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I'm answering my own question to solve it, if anyone needs it later. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question here. @dbugger pointed out that it was a good practice to wrap functions in jquery in a document ready block. So here it is if anyone needs it:

**jquery code**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        var images = [];
        images[0] = "http://localhost:3000/images/pdf_template.png";
        images[1] = "http://localhost:3000/images/watermark_template.png";

        var x = 0;
        setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);

        function displayNextImage() {
            x = x < images.length - 1 ? x : 0;
            $("#img").fadeOut(300, function(){
              $(this).attr('src', images[x]).fadeIn(300);
            })
            x++;
        }
});
```

As you can see, the only change here is the addition of the `jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {});` block.